# why is const_missing not triggered when dynamically creating class

Tags: ruby

I have the following example:

```
class Test
  def self.const_missing(const)
    puts const
  end
end


Test2 = Class.new(Test) do
  CONST
end

class Test3 < Test
  CONST
end
```

I was under the impression that since const_missing is defined in the parent class, the call of CONST, a undefined const will trigger the method and puts out "CONST". However in the above example, class Test3 behaves like what i thought whereas Test2, which is dynamically generated using Class.new inherited from Test, does not. The const_missing method is not triggered for Test2. It just gives me: 'uninitialized const CONST'

I am wondering what the reason is?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`Class.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-c-new) documentation:

> If a block is given, it is passed the class object, and the block is evaluated in the context of this class using `class_eval`.

Let's take a look at the [`Module#class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) documentation (emphasis mine):

> Evaluates the string or block in the context of *mod*, **except that when a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected.** This can be used to add methods to a class.

Therefore in your `Test2` case:

```
Test2 = Class.new(Test) do
  CONST # equivalent to ::CONST
end
```

And for `Test3`:

```
class Test3 < Test
  CONST # equivalent to self::CONST
end
```

Reopening the class after using `Class.new` (and naming it by assigning its return value to a constant like `Test2`) and then referencing an undefined constant has the behavior you're expecting:

```
Test2 = Class.new(Test)
class Test2
  CONST
end
```

Or explicitly writing the *path* where `CONST` should be looked up:

```
Test2 = Class.new(Test) do
  self::CONST
end
```

Comment: Does the 'mod' in the documentation "Evaluates the string or block in the context of mod, except that when a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected. " refer to the enclosing module? in this case, is it referring to the 'main' object?

Comment: @yuzhoul: *mod* is `Class.new(Test)`. However the const/cvar lookup context is toplevel / main here.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. However if const lookup context is toplevel/main and main is a instance of Object. Shouldn't a failed lookup goes to const_missing method defined on top level, ie.move the const_missing method from above example outside of any class. I tried that, still not triggered...

Comment: @yuzhoul: You have to define `Object.const_missing`.